# Nuxt SSR project use 100% CPU

Tags: node.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxt for server side rendering. I finished this project but at the last stage when i deploy to production, nuxt or ssr (idk) use 100% cpu on the system side. For this reason centos machine stop running.

Have you any suggestion about this problem? What should i look?

Comment: You most likely have some recursion somewhere, have you tried testing locally first to see what's going on? Is your souce code anywhere to be seen/read like a public github repo?

Comment: we are doing load test always. In load test, when came 1000 user, cpu goes to 100% and machine gone! its big project so i cant show you much thing. but its my nuxt.config.js https://codepen.io/akagamina/pen/VwwpBMa @MichaelB

Comment: Hmm, isn't that normal behaviour into a load test when going over the physical limits of the machine? Have you tried a load test with 500-600-700 etc. to see exactly where the breakpoint is?

Comment: actually we use express before, for some reasons scratch from rewrite with nuxt. if we do load test to old project(express) there is no problem. yes cpu 100% again but machine not stoping. but with nuxt, cpu 100% yes but also machine stopped. sorry for my bad english.

Comment: your machine stopped is a problem of configuration of your machine. None of userland app should cause this. And yes its totally expected that nuxt is slower than barebone express app

Comment: so this not good for me? so did you know any configuration for front end side?

Comment: What is the detail of your server exactly? Are you using PM2?

Comment: still i have this problem, and i am using pm2 @nmfzone, i run nuxt project with analyze,  and there is no big data. just normal but i didnt understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem. All i had to do is;

```
'pm2 start npm --name server -i max -- run start'
```

When you use;

```
pm2 start npm --name server -- run start
```

node working just one core, but when you use '-i max' node working maximum capability of your server.

maybe this info good for anyone...